# Booting a Druid Cluster using Whirr

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-whirr, druid

I am trying to boot a Druid cluster using Whirr following the steps in Druid website http://druid.io/docs/latest/Booting-a-production-cluster.html

The cluster is instantiated, but the different Druid nodes (overlord, middleManager, historical and coordinator) have the following error downloading some dependencies causing them to fail

> Failed to collect dependencies at
>   io.druid.extensions:druid-s3-extensions:jar:0.6.115

Did anyone face a similar issue or know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may have been answered in the [Druid dev discussion group on Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/druid-development/whirr/druid-development/cA_1_4FiUvU/G6Pp2uUxPRQJ). Basically it's an incompatibility with JDK versions > 1.7.0_45. Downgrading to 1.7.0_45 seems to have helped people.